# bounds property gives wrong information

Tags: iphone, ios, uiviewcontroller, bounds

I have just run template from Xcode (Master-Detail Application for iPhone). I only added

```
NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromCGRect(self.view.bounds));
```

in DetailViewController:viewdidLoad

and when I rotated the screen (on Simulator) on MasterViewController to Landscape next I pushed a DetailViewController, in console I've seen:

```
   {{0, 0}, {320, 460}}
```

which is not correct because, view is in Landscape.

Any idea why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your view's bounds is portrait by default.

If you launch your application in landscape mode, a rotation message is sent to view controller before it appears. so try to print in `viewDidAppear`.

Answer (score 0):

Did you add into you detail view:
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    return YES;
}

If yes, then you should print those values in viewWillAppear because maybe the screen is loaded in portrait by default then it is rotated right after loaded.

Comment: I don't think so, by default is (in shouldAutorotate...)     return (interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown); and what is worth to say didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation is not called.

Comment: I did not tell you didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation will be called, and I told you that view is loaded, not appear.

Comment: you said that it is rotated after loaded, from apple documentation -viewDidLoad -> Called after the controller’s view is loaded into memory. So from your answer, somebody could think that in viewDidLoad can get a proper bounds, which is not correct answer.